# Using Runtime, UAC and Security Manager in JAVA

Tags: java, permissions, uac, securitymanager

Pls am trying to run this code:

```
try{
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = runtime.exec("netsh wlan show hostednetwork");
}
catch (Exception e){}
```

i then get this error:

```
You must run this command at an administrator privilege.
```

After several manipulations, it gave me this:

```
Supply an Administrator password.
```

which i dont have. pls how can i rectify this. thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like you understand the Java, Windows appears to be your problem.   If you don't have admin priv on this box you are out of luck

Comment: is it possible to bypass the UAC from my program? or allow my program to prompt the user for UAC, after which i will then use the output

Comment: That would negate the need for UAC.   If this was *nix you could run your java setuid.   Perfect call for a Windows StackExchange, perhaps SuperUser or ServerFault could help

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try using Windows `runas` program. It allows you to execute command with authentication of another user.

This MSDN article contains neccesary information: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx?mfr=true

You may run `runas` without being prompted for password, but you'll have to type it in `.exec()` as plain text, or you may want to try to use keyboard-interactive authentication with `runas`.